# Is this a binary search tree? inorder travesal

Tags: search, tree, binary, inorder

**I'm trying to find whether the given tree is a binary search tree or not and I'm getting an error that 
cannot find the symbol 'root'.**

```
class BinaryTree{
 ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
   List copy=new ArrayList(list);
    Collections.sort(copy);
    if(list.equals(copy)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void inorder(Node root){
    if(root.left!=null){
        inorder(root.left);
    }
    list.add(root.data);
    if(root.right!=null){
        inorder(root.right);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    tree.root = new Node(s.nextInt());  
    tree.root.left = new Node(s.nextInt()); 
    tree.root.right = new Node(s.nextInt()); 
    tree.root.left.left = new Node(s.nextInt()); 
    tree.root.left.right = new Node(s.nextInt()); 
    if(tree.checkBST(root)) 
        System.out.println("Yes"); 
    else
        System.out.println("No"); 
}
}
```

Comment: class `BinaryTree` has no member called `root`. What's the definition of `Node`?

Comment: `class Node{
         int data;
         Node left,right;
        public Node(int data){
        left=right=null;
       }
  }`